# Concavity of a two variables function with zero Hessian

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I'm stuck on an exercises that asks me to find all values of $a$ for which the following function is strictly concave in the first quadrant:
$$g(x, y) = \left(\frac{1}{3}x^{-a} + \frac{2}{3}y^{-a}\right)^{-1/a}$$
where $a \neq 0$ is a real number.
Hence the conditions: $x > 0, y > 0$.

So I tried to rewrite the function in a "simpler" form, and I concluded I can write it as
$$g(x, y) = \sqrt[a]{3} \frac{xy}{(2x^a + y^a)^{1/a}}$$

Now the question then reduces to find the values of $a$ for which is concave the function

$$\frac{xy}{(2x^a + y^a)^{1/a}}$$

Now the problem is that going with the study of the Hessian matrix ends up in nothing for the determinant is zero.
In this way I don't know how to proceed.

I asked the same question on MathSE, but after some day I decided to ask it here too for nobody answered me (not even a hint).

Can you please help me with this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Let
\begin{equation*}
 h(x,y)=-\frac{2(a+1)}{9}(xy)^{-a-2}\Big(\frac13 x^{-a}+\frac23 y^{-a}\Big)^{-1/a-2}. \tag{1}
\end{equation*}
By direct calculating,
\begin{align*}
 \frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial x^2 } &= y^2 h(x,y), \\
 \frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial y^2 } &= x^2 h(x,y), \\
 \frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial x\partial y } &=-xy h(x,y).
\end{align*}
Hence, the Hessian of g may be written as
\begin{equation*}
 H(x,y)\stackrel{\mathrm{def}}{=}\begin{pmatrix}\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial x^2 }&\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial x\partial y }\\
 \frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial x\partial y }&\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial x\partial y } \end{pmatrix}
 = h(x,y) \begin{pmatrix}y\\ -x \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}y&-x\end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation*}
Since the $2\times 2$-matrix $\begin{pmatrix}y\\ -x \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}y&-x\end{pmatrix}$ is positive definite, so the positive/negative definiteness of Hassian matrix $H(x,y)$ is defined by the $h(x,y)$.
From (1), if $a<-1$, then $h(x,y)>0$, $H(x,y)$ is (semi-)positive definite and $ h(x,y)$ is convex,  if $a>-1$, then $h(x,y)<0$, $H(x,y)$ is (semi-)negative definite and $ h(x,y)$ is concave.

Comment: I don't get how you managed to obtain a non zero Hessian whereas I kept getting a zero Hessian determinant...

Comment: @Numb3rs Thank you for your replication. I add several words to interpret the positive/negative definiteness of $H(x,y)$.